# how to make multiple connections in python using discord gateway?

Tags: python-3.x, discord

please tell me how I can implement the following: I receive data via a websocket through a discord gateway, the task is how to do it so that I can receive not only one token account, but let’s say if I add several more tokens to the database so that I can listen to them via the websocket? That is, it automatically began to listen, as if it took these tokens and also established connections using them and listened to them via a websocket.
I don’t know in advance how many a token can be, so it is necessary that when adding a new socket connection with this token is created

I was thinking about how to implement this through Docker so that a Docker container would be created if a token appeared, if it appeared in the database, maybe there are other ways